# Responsive Design on Menu using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I'm fairly new to CSS and Media Queries for responsive design so I decided to use Twitter bootstrap.

I used their responsive files to help me out, but I have a problem with the menu as you can see here:

[image]

The dropdown images from each section of the menu don't seem to "push" the other options downwards. The site can be found [here](http://fomgsd.com/test/).

Here's the media query on my custom css file:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
    .container {width: 940px}

    #solutions{
        min-width: 1090px;
        position: absolute;
        left: -100px;
    }

    #services{
        min-width: 1090px;
        position: absolute;
        left: -190px;
    }


    #support{
        min-width: 840px;
        position: absolute;
        left: -276px;
    }
}
```

Can you help me with the menu? Do I need to add my own media query?

Comment: it's working fine... i tested in mozilla developer tools..

Comment: but does it look like the screenshot?

Comment: Your live version works fine, but without markup or CSS to look at, there's no way to tell what's wrong with your local version... That being said, post your code.

Comment: I updated with my custom css

Answer (score 0):

```
            #solutions{
                    min-width: 960px;
                    position: absolute;
                    left: -100px;
                    }
```

Try to change this id width form `1090px` to less than `960px`